# What happens when async=true is used inside document.ready?

Tags: javascript

What does happen when we call a javascript with attribute `async="true"` inside `document.ready`. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ma = document.createElement('script');
ma.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ma.async = true;
ma.src = 'test.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ma,s);
});
```

Script inside `$(document).ready` will be executed immediately after the DOM is loaded. What does happen if we put `async = true`for calling a script inside it? `test.js` will be loaded before DOM is ready?

Comment: No, test.js will not be loaded before DOM is ready since all of your code above will only execute after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts added via DOM manipulation *are not synchronous* wrt the JavaScript that adds them, independent of the `async` attribute.

The [`async` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) plays a larger role in scripts that exist in the initial HTML - before the "ready" - or when multiple script elements are added and the execution order must match the DOM insertion order:

> Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser should, if possible, execute the script asynchronously ..
>
> .. script-inserted scripts execute asynchronously in IE and WebKit, but synchronously [wrt the insertion order of the script elements] in Opera and pre-4.0 Firefox. .. To request script-inserted external scripts be executed in the insertion order in browsers [..] set `async=false` on the scripts you want to maintain order ..

The browser will start loading the script referenced by the new script element "at some point after the element is added to the DOM" and the referenced script will only execute once loaded. However, `insertBefore` returns *immediately* and the referenced script is *not* guaranteed to be loaded - doesn't matter what `async` is set to.

---

In this case, the test.js code is guaranteed to only run "at some point *after* the script element is added" to the DOM - this must naturally be *after* ready function is called, which is where the element is added.

Since browsers have a single execution context, and adding the DOM element is an asynchronous operation (wrt the external script being executed), this also means that the code in test.js will *only* run "at some *after* the ready function ends". And, the ready function will not start (or end) before it is called in response to "DOM ready".

Setting the `async` flag (to any value) does not change the above.

Comment: test.js contains references to DOM elements. This code will not throw JavaScript error 'element not found' as it will be executed only after DOM is ready, right ? Will this work correctly in all browsers?

Comment: @user3090914 I've moved my previous comment into the answer. Also, FWIW, I recommend using the `$(function ..)` shorthand, from a stylistic preference.